# Fill a select multiple

Tags: angular

I have an array of values ​​that I want to see reflected by default in a multiple select.

```
        <select multiple class="form-control" id="alergias_medicamentos" formControlName="alergias_medicamentos"  [(ngModel)]="pacienteExpediente.alergias_medicamentos">
          <option>Antibióticos</option>
          <option>Ciprofloxacina</option>
          <option>Lidocaína</option>
          <option>Penicilina</option>
        </select>
```

["Ciprofloxacina","Lidocaína"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are having issues, trying removing either `formControlName` or `[(ngModel)]` as they are most likely conflicting.